# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Default Identity user CRUD

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am new to ASP.NET MVC.

I have created an application using default identity individual user accounts.
I am trying to implement an admin panel and I would like to view all the users, their roles and edit / delete them (CRUD Operation).

I came across the following:

> userManager.Users.ToList();

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return userManager.Users.ToList();
}
```

I have tried researching regarding the same. Unfortunately, I am unable to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET Identity 2.0 which you are probably using, what you need is exposed on the UserManager and RoleManager.

```
userManager.Users.ToList();
roleManager.Roles.ToList();
```

You can use those two managers to create roles and assign roles to users. For example to get users in specific roles you can do something like that:

```
var users = roleManager.FindByName(roleName).Users.Select(x => x.UserId);
```

To delete user you can do something like that:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(string id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        var logins = user.Logins;
        var rolesForUser = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(id);

        using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            foreach (var login in logins.ToList())
            {
                await _userManager.RemoveLoginAsync(login.UserId, new UserLoginInfo(login.LoginProvider, login.ProviderKey));
            }

            if (rolesForUser.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in rolesForUser.ToList())
                {
                    // item should be the name of the role
                    var result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user.Id, item);
                }
            }

            await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And if you would like to update an user then:

```
var user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())

user.Email = AppUserViewModel.Email;
user.FName = AppUserViewModel.FName;
user.LName = AppUserViewModel.LName;
user.DOB = AppUserViewModel.DOB;
user.Gender = AppUserViewModel.Gender;

var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

Comment: Hello Dawid, thanks a alot for the response. I'll try this out and get back.

Comment: I hope it will help!